# MySQL & Basic Maths in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to call, say;

```
$timestamp = 1392444177;
$response = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM carts WHERE timestamp<:timestamp");
$response->execute(array(':timestamp' => $timestamp));
$result = $response->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ARRAY);
var_dump($result);
```

Notice the use of the less than symbol? How could I best perform this? The datatype of column 'timestamp' is currently INT(40).

Comment: suggestion: i think not need to make column `int(40)` it is sufficient to `int(10)` for 10 digit timestamp

Comment: I suppose that's sufficient for the next 19-20 years or so, good call @SatishSharma! Not sure why it's int(40), it was set by my colleague. I'll change that.

Comment: discuss with your colleague and effectively any suggession reply me also may be it will also useful for me in future.

Comment: @satishsharma Just INT (or BIGINT) will suffice. The number (40) or (10) or (11) serves no purpose in this instance.